# Limit user posts in php

Tags: php, html

I am fairly new to php. I have a site where members are able to make posts on certain topics. I am trying to place a limit on said posts. I have developed a crude method using $_SESSION and isset. This method is not user-friendly for it requires the user to refresh the page if they do not adhere to the 1 post per so many seconds policy. Is there a better way to go about doing this, I have done quite a bit of research and am turning up empty?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['posted']))
 $_SESSION['posted'] = time();

if (time()-$_SESSION['posted'] < 12)
 die('Post limit exceeded. Please hit refresh');
else
 $_SESSION['posted'] = time();
```

Comment: you could use an ajax test to run this check in the "background" and disable the submission if the time limit is wrong. but you'd STILL need to do this check on the server even when the form does get submitted, in case someone tries to bypass the JS code.

Comment: Do you really want to tie this to a user session?  What is to stop a bot that doesn't accept cookies or propagate a session id from posting at a rate beyond what you desire? Many times throttling limits like this are tied to IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be checked both at the client side and at the server side.

- On the client side, you need to use cookie to track number of recent posts and javascript to make sure the user is not exceeding the limit before sending the request to the server.
- Because users can bypass this by sending raw http requests, you need to check on the server side as well. In this case using $_SESSION is not enough because the user can still modify the session variables. You have to query the db and make sure the request is valid.

Comment: There is no way to manipulate the values stored in sessions from the client side.

That's one of the main reasons you'd use a session over a cookie - YOU control the data. With cookies, the user can manipulate the data.

The only way to access/manipulate session data from the client side would be with an Ajax call or other JavaScript mechanism to call another php script, which would be doing the retrieval/manipulation of the session data via the session_ functions.

Comment: I meant php tracks session by an `id` in the cookie, if you remove it, you are in a fresh session, and can make more posts.